# Issues running USRP_UHD v6.1.0 with RH 2.0.8

Tags: redhawksdr

I am Running RH 2.0.8 on CentOS 7.2. Attempting to control Ettus N210 using v6.1.0 of the USRP_UHD Device. From the IDE console, I can see the `USRP_UHD recognize/initialize the N210`. I can allocate a channel (1MHz BW, 2Msps) from the available RX_Digitizer.

My issue - I connect to dataShort out with the IDE Plot Data and never see any data or SRI updates.

Using wireshark, I see data being output from the N210 over the network connection, just nothing plots. Same issue whether I launch Device via node/domain manager or in Sandbox.

Similar issue if I launch a waveform with a USRP_UHD dependency - connects & allocates properly but I never any data sent to the connected component in the waveform.

Curious if anyone else has had a similar experience.

UPDATE 12/17/2018: 
After installing RH 2.2.1 on a CentOS 7.4 system, the USRP_UHD device appears to work correctly out of the box. I'm able to plot data and SRI from the dataShort_out port after allocating an RX_DIGITIZER.

Answer (score 2):

The output port of the `USRP_UHD` is what is called a multi-out port, which is slightly different from a normal BulkIO output port. The main difference is that the port will only send data over connections which have a connection ID that has been mapped to a stream ID. With the `USRP_UHD`, this is done via allocation and the allocation ID. Read more [here](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/connections/bulkio/multiout-ports/).

To plot data from a multi-out port using the IDE, the plot must be connected to the port using a connection ID that has been mapped to a stream ID, which for the `USRP_UHD` means the connection ID must be identical to one of the allocation IDs. You can specify the connection ID using the plotting wizard, or you can create a listener allocation with an allocation ID set to the connection ID of the plot (either option will work). See the following resources for more information:

- [Port Plot Wizard](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/ide/plot-port-wizard/)
- [Plotting a Tuned Receiver](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/devices/interacting-with-hardware/using-fei-device-ide/#plotting-a-tuned-receiver)
- [Allocating a Listener](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/devices/interacting-with-hardware/using-fei-device-ide/#attaching-a-listener-to-a-tuned-receiver)

Connecting a waveform to a multi-out port must follow the same conventions and connect using a connection ID that has been mapped to a stream. This can be done by adding an FEI device dependency to the waveform `*.sad.xml` file (see first bullet below). This can also be done after launching a waveform (that does not contain an FEI device dependency) by specifying the connection ID for the connection between the waveform and the multi-out port. The connection ID will need to be identical to an allocation ID associated with the stream of data desired, which could be a listener allocation or the original control allocation. See the second and third bullets below for more information on this method.

- [Associating a Waveform with an FEI Device](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/devices/associating-a-waveform/)
- [Allocating a Listener](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/devices/interacting-with-hardware/using-fei-device-ide/#attaching-a-listener-to-a-tuned-receiver)
- [Connect Wizard](https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.1/manual/ide/connect-wizard/)

Note: Though the links I've provided are to the REDHAWK 2.2.1 manual, the content is applicable to all versions of REDHAWK, including REDHAWK 2.0.8. The IDE features you will need are also available in REDHAWK 2.0.8. The 2.0.8 manual should have similar content if you'd prefer to use the older manual.